# How to handle ClientId in multi-tenant database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, architecture

I have a multi-tenant database with strict and critical data separation between clients. Before putting it into production, I would like to know if my approach makes sense or could lead to problems down the road (security/performance/maintenance). Below 2 models are the typical scenario:

```
public class Car
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int carId {get;set;}

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int clientId {get;set;}

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Component> components {get;set;}
}

public class Component
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int componentId {get;set;}

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int clientId {get;set;}

    ...

    [ForeignKey("carId, clientId")]
    public Car car {get;set;}
    public int carId {get;set}
}
```

This way, every model has the clientId as a Primary Key, forcing it to be used with .Find() and forcing it into join-tables for many-many relationships. That means there's quite a bit of redundancy and the clientId is used when a query is actually quite safe for data separation.

Does it make sense to force the clientId into just anything or might it be better to only keep it on the parent models?

Comment: clientId as a Primary Key? or its a foreign key?

Comment: In above code, clientId forms a composite key together with the actual id property. But that's what I'm struggling with. Include it in the composite PK and force it into queries as an additional "checker", or keep it out and only use it on the parent models. Especially security is a concern. I can't see implications down the road because I don't have the experience.

Comment: why not use tenant per schema?

Comment: Is this a desktop application or a web site? How the clients will connect to SQL Server, user/pass or Windows autenthication?

Comment: Sorry I missed that, it's an API. The database is used by SimpleMembershipProvider as well as general data for the clients. I would exclude tenant per schema, because the data size (relatively small per client) and cost structure of the service make a multi-tenant approach more viable, also in terms of maintenance and deployment.

Answer (score 1):

It's my opinion that this is the right way to go. We designed with client only on the patent tables and have since moved towards denormalizing it into various child table. This means it can be used in queries driven from the child table. It also allows us to partition tables by client.

Answer (score 1):

If I was designing this, I’d make sure the application code that operates the database is thoroughly tested and written in high quality vs adding redundancy in this way.

Adding redundancy in this way will make your code and database more difficult to manage and I guess it can lead to performance issues too (I don’t have enough details to make a firm claim but it looks like it).

Comment: The redundancy here is an extra integer field on all child tables as well as 2 extra integers on the join tables. So it's still manageable, but it's there.